# Get Particular file form MPMediaItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmediaitem

I am using `MPMediaItem`, and getting all songs from library.
My issue is, if i want to get only particular file which I want.
Anybody can know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MpMediaItem provides property like

- MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle
- MPMediaItemPropertyArtist
- MPMediaItemPropertyGenre
- MPMediaItemPropertyComposer
- MPMediaItemPropertyTitle

By using above properties you can identify the file which you want.